# How to write or modify EXIF data for an existing image on the filesystem, without loading the image?

Tags: ios, metadata, exif

I've asked similar questions before, but have not received a definitive answer. Seems that there must be a way to simply add/modify metadata to an image without loading the image into memory, without having to deal with directly reading bits.

Seems like ways exist when using `CMSampleBufferRef`s, but I need to be able to do this with a regular image already saved to disk.
For instance, given a very large `png` at `/Documents/photo.png`, I want to modify its exif metadata without having to load that image.

Comment: Related: [Is there any easy way to edit jpeg marker data in-place?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10508410/85950)

Comment: Since @H2CO3 provided you with perhaps the only solution you can use (I didn't have one), please accept his answer.

Comment: Please also note that if you don't accept any answer, you still won't get the bounty's value back. So it would only be a benefit for one of the answerers if you accepted one of the answers. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use libexif - I've had success with compiling it for iOS before. With libexif, you can modify any image's EXIF metadata.

Comment: Sure, but does this framework load the image into memory first?

Comment: That's good. Could you provide an example of such usage with libexif? i.e. loading the metadata and writing it back to the file.

Comment: @akaru this is how I implemented EXIF metadata reading and writing in my file manager app: https://github.com/H2CO3/MyFile/blob/master/src/MFImageMetadataController.m

Comment: Thanks, @H2CO3, I'll look into this. If you happen to know where I can grab an iOS build or XCode project of libexif for iOS, let me know.

Comment: @akaru I don't know about one, but I think the source of libexif should compile out of the box in Xcode.

Comment: Btw I'd appreciate having accepted my answer if it was helpful for you :)

Comment: @akaru Did you manage to build libexif for iOS?  I'm having difficulty doing so.

Comment: @SebastianDwornik [here is](http://apt.thebigboss.org/onepackage.php?bundleid=libexif) an iOS build of libexif by me.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank you.  How did you built it by the way?  Was it difficult?

Comment: @SebastianDwornik Not difficult at all if you have experience crossing stuff. Because the Apple toolchain is not entirely GNU, the standard configure - make - make install workflow won't work, but in general I just manually patch `config.h` then compile all the c files together using a manually created Makefile.

Comment: And here I was thinking I could do it simply through XCode.  I'm still trying to extract that .DEB file you provided.  Perhaps the Makefile might be easier.  ;)

Comment: @SebastianDwornik I never use Xcode :) And use `dpkg -x filename.deb directory` to extract the Debian package.

Comment: Extracted finally just before your comment.  :)

Comment: @H2CO3 Just looking at the code, doesn't `[MFPictureMetadata save]` load the entire image into memory before writing the EXIF?  You have a call there to `jpeg_data_load_file()`

Comment: @EricBrochu (OMG that code of mine from some 2 years ago is so horrible I can't even express. Look at that chained if-else and the superfluous local `malloc()`s, aaargh...!) Indeed, it does, but I'm not sure it's a must. In fact, I'm pretty confident that's not how it should be done. Seeing the quality of that piece of code of mine... I don't even assume I got the usage of the library right.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to modify the EXIF, you can modify the binary data directly from the file. Just replace in the image the binary portion with the new one. 
I don't know if objective-c permit this, but in ansi c should be simple. The complicate part is to identify the exact part to change.