# Edit Exif Data in iOS Photos Gallery/ LIbrary without Creating Another Copy

Tags: ios, exif, alassetslibrary, photokit, libexif

Is there a way to edit/ modify the exif data of the photot that are part of iOS photo library / gallery on the iPhone. Whenever I try to do that, iOS tries to save it as a separate image file. However, I would like to modify the exif data, without creating another copy of the photo. I used libexif as mentioned in the links below, however libexif lets you read and modify the data, but I could not figure out a way to store in the same file. 
Gallery APIs  in IOS (ALAsset, PhotoKit) do not seem to provide direct access to underlying physical file. They only provide APIs using which the image content can be accessed/ updated or inserted. They do not seem to have  apis to modify the exif data. Also, libexif seems to work on the raw filename path. Is there a way to get the raw filename using PhotoKit or ALAsset ?

Am I missing something? Any help or pointers will be deeply appreciated.

[How to write or modify EXIF data for an existing image on the filesystem, without loading the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715631/how-to-write-or-modify-exif-data-for-an-existing-image-on-the-filesystem-withou)

[Save original image data with modified metadata (no re-encoding) on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624384/save-original-image-data-with-modified-metadata-no-re-encoding-on-ios)