# Edit EXIF metadata in RAW photos in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, exif

I need to edit `EXIF` data into a `RAW` (`CR2/NEF`) file with `iOS`. Unfortunately, the only way to manage It with `Cocoa` Framework is `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);`, but this method compress my `RAW` from approximately 40MB to 10MB.
Is there some method to open my file on `iOS` app and edit `EXIF` without losing compression? 
Is there some methods to edit `EXIF` data on `RAW` directly on file, avoiding the allocation on `UIImage` (quality loss) and using, for example, `NSData`?

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125323/problem-setting-exif-data-for-an-image

Comment: Check this post [How to write or modify EXIF data for an existing image on the filesystem, without loading the image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715631/how-to-write-or-modify-exif-data-for-an-existing-image-on-the-filesystem-withou)

Comment: Neither of the link above works for RAW files. Both of them load the image as JPEG and ruin everything :(

Comment: Did you ever figure this out Alessia?